# Imaginary of complex coordinates

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

[image]

Hi I'm wondering how to find the value of Im(a). Is that just the y value of the coordinate of a. This is all the problem has given me. I'm confused in terms of how to solve it. FYI the hexagon is regular with a side length of $\sqrt2$

Comment: If it's a regular hexagon, this is a no-brainer.

Comment: There is a lot of context missing here.  Is that hexagon regular?  i.e. are all of the sides of the same length and angles of the same measure?

Comment: yes the hexagon is regular

Comment: @SeanRoberson How do you find the imaginary part of the conjugate if thats all you're given

Comment: @XanderHenderson the hexagon is regular. How would you use that to help

Comment: is there any information about the angle $\angle Im$ $0$ $a$

Comment: To start find radius $R$ draw right triangle $ \sin \pi/6= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt2 R}$

Answer (score 1):

The interior angles are all $120^0$ (you can divide the hexagon into $4$ triangles).  $1-i=\sqrt2 e^{-\frac{\pi i}4}$.

Therefore, $\operatorname{arg}a=\frac{2\pi}3-\frac{\pi}4=\frac{5\pi}{12}$.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Custer \begin{align*} 
a &= e^{2\pi i/3} (1-i) = \left(\cos (2\pi/3) + i \sin (2\pi/3) \right) (1-i) \\
&= \left(-\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i \right) (1-i) \\
&= -\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \left( \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right) i.
\end{align*} Thats how i solved it